# C# Disposing and Ressurrecting/Loading Bitmaps using a Dictionary

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, dispose

i have written a programm that uses some picture ressources and creates a file from them.
As a Customer preview the images are shown before they get worked with. Therefore i need to dispose them before i can work with them. But i want to load the preview again afterwards and since it might be a huge number of pictures I want to do it dynamically, there i fail.

I use a Dictionary with the filename as String:

```
            //Creating a Bitmap so we can preview the Picture.
        try
        {
            mainDrawingBackgroundBitmap = new Bitmap(filePathBackgroundBackgroundImage);

            if(mainAllBitmapsDictionary.ContainsKey(mainDrawingBackgroundBitmap))
            {
                mainAllBitmapsDictionary.Remove(mainDrawingBackgroundBitmap);
            }     
            mainAllBitmapsDictionary.Add(mainDrawingBackgroundBitmap,filePathBackgroundBackgroundImage);
        }
```

Now my Bitmap and path are in the Dictionary, later i dispose them this way:

```
        private void DisposeAllFiles()
    {
        foreach (var tempBitmap in mainAllBitmapsDictionary.Keys)
        {
            tempBitmap.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Which works just fine.
Now when i try to recreate the Bitmaps:

```
        private void RessurrectAllFiles()
    {
        foreach (var tempAllBitmap in mainAllBitmapsDictionary)
        {
            try
            {
                var tempBitmap = tempAllBitmap.Key;
                tempBitmap = new Bitmap(tempAllBitmap.Value);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ae)
            {
            }
        }

    }
```

He doesn't fail or throw an error, the Dictionary even gets filled with Correct Bitmaps and strings but, those don't seem to affect the original objects anymore, so the Dictionary is as it was but when i inspect a Bitmap like the: mainDrawingBackgroundBitmap, i only see ArgumentExceptions.

To put it bluntly, where do i fail?

Answer (score 1):

Keep path to images as keys, and bitmap data as values, so then it will be easy to you to manipulate data and searching dictionary will perform fast.

```
Dictionary<string, Bitmap>
```

Comment: Sorry but how does this relate to my problem? Also i think its the same speed searching for an Object or a String, anyway i have no intend to search for/manipulate something.

Comment: @Master117 by calling `var tempBitmap = tempAllBitmap.Key;` you are creating a local copy of the variable and not in any way modifying the original dictionary value. Following Kresimir's advice will solve this issue, as the string values are not changing. Having it the other way around also makes much more sense from a logical point of view.

Comment: The problem is, neither as Value nor as Key is: tempAllBitmap.Value = new Bitmap(tempAllBitmap.Key); or the opposit allowed.
Also Multiple Bitmaps may have the same path/string therefore i think using the string as Key might be troublesome

Comment: @Master117 How is it possible that different bitmaps come from the same file? Also, `tempAllBitmap.Value` is allowed, why do you say it's not?

Comment: @Rotem tempAllBitmap.Value <-- is allowed but 

tempAllBitmap.Value = new Bitmap(tempAllBitmap.Key); <<-- is not allowed 
(this would be a try when the bitmap is the value to set the new picture for the old bitmap):
Fehler 9 Einer Eigenschaft oder einem Indexer "System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.Drawing.Bitmap,string>.Value" kann nichts zugewiesen werden -- sie sind schreibgeschützt. 

Translation: Error 9: a "System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.Drawing.Bitmap,string>.Value" can't be anything declared to, they are writeprotected

Comment: @Master117 you must do this by resetting the dictionary key. e.g.: `theDictionary[theKey] = theNewValue;`

Comment: That  works, dunno how i missed that, thanks! Now i got some other problem apparently one may not change the values and keys during foreach, thanks anyway!